# How can I control the commit size while writing to text file using kettle?

Tags: kettle

I have a oracle table "order" which has a clob column "description" and also primary key is varchar2 "Id". I am reading that column and for every record in the table I am writing to a txt file - order_Id.txt. Table has about 400000000 records and writing to files using text file output is giving outofmemory heap error and gc overhead limit exceeded. How can I process data in chunks ?

1. Tweaked -Xmx settings in spoon.bat
2. m/c has 16gb RAM

***ADDITIONAL DETAILS ***
1. These are settings in spoon.bat. I am using kettle PDI 7.0
set PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms5500m" "-Xmx15000m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=12384m"
2. I have set KETTLE_FILE_OUTPUT_MAX_STREAM_COUNT and KETTLE_FILE_OUTPUT_MAX_STREAM_LIFE also to 1000
3. Still I see its not completing\flushing files. It continues to write blank files and finally breaks
4. I have attached a screenshot with exact steps I am doing
[image]

Answer (score 0):

How big is that clob?
Data is already processed in chunks, but if your rows of data are very large then you may run out of memory.

By default each hop (buffer) between steps takes 10k rows. When the buffer fills up the previous step waits and stops sending rows until there’s capacity.

You can decrease the number of rows that fit in the hops under the transformation properties (right-click in an empty region of the canvas). It’s ser per transformation and the smaller the buffer the slower the transformation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I tried reducing no of rows also. I have now attached more details to my question